# Files not answering when trying to restore a file from Recycle Bin

Tags: nautilus, trash

I'm trying to restore a file which I had previously deleted on Ubuntu 19.04. When I click *Restore File* in the recycle bin, Files does not respond.
Here's the issue:

[image]

Comment: There might be a problem in ~/.local/share/Trash (maybe permissions). Type "nautilus" in a terminal and reproduce the bug, so you can see what is wrong.

Comment: @JerareYoshi Where shall i do it? Should i type `cd ~/.local/share/Trash` first? Then `nautilus`?

Comment: Just start nautilus from the terminal and then use it normally. This way, you will be able to see error messages from the launched nautilus window in the terminal. Maybe first end nautilus completely, i.e., `killall nautilus && nautilus' will first end all instances, then launch a new window.

Comment: Don't know how, but i no longer have this issue. Thinking about what i've done that may helped to solve it i found two things: installing and deleting kubuntu-desktop and mySQL.